# Selection statements and checks against NULL

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am programming with C language , noticed something strange after defining a `struct` as below then tried to print out a string in `main()`:

```
struct node{
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};

int main(){
  struct node test;
  test.value = 10;
  test.next = NULL;
  if(test.next->value > 100)
      printf("%s\n", "Big");
  return 0;
}
```

This program was compiled successfully , but I got a segmentation fault when it was run , I know `test.next->value` is illegal while `test.next` = NULL , and this segmentation fault can be avoided if it's written just like this :

```
if(test.next && test.next->value > 100) 
    printf("%s\n", "Big");
```

But it's more ugly now , I have to write this kind style in other programs to avoid segfault , to make console just print out nothing , is there a better way to write it elegantly ? :)

Comment: you are trying to access value of null pointer so segmentation fault. In 2nd case test.next returns false so nothing printed on screen.

Comment: Although it is ugly, this is correct. To make it print, you must have a `value` greater than 100.

Comment: Yes i know that , but oftenly i need to determine if test.next->value > 100 without knowing if test.next == NULL , how can i write it more prettier ?

Comment: Haha ok , thanks anyway

Comment: haha that's funny , i just want to write it correctly without repeating so much , i hate to repeat any similar code

Comment: You can write a macro, like this -> `#define NODE_NXT_VAL_CMP(Y, X) (Y && Y->value > X)` and use it wherever required in your program like this --> `if(NODE_NXT_VAL_CMP(test.next, 100)) {...`.

Comment: Thank you H.S. , i will try your method  :)

Comment: Keep in mind that the macro obfuscates, and it can evaluate `Y` twice. It doesn't make the expression any shorter or clearer, so it doesn't help the OP's goal at all. It's simply not a good idea! (On top of that, it's buggy. `(Y && Y->value > X)` should be `((Y) && (Y)->value > (X))`.)

Comment: @H.S. -- `if(test.next && test.next->value > 100) { /* ... */ }` is clear, correct, and idiomatic. Writing a macro for this only serves to obfuscate the code. In addition, your macro is unsafe; at least put parentheses around individual arguments.

Comment: @DavidBowling: OP question says - _i have to write this kind style in other programs..._, so, this suggestion is just to avoid writing the same code again and again. Yes, parenthesis is something I missed. Also, I agree that writing code in this way `if(test.next && test.next->value > 100)` is clear that's why I did not write it as an answer but just a comment.

Comment: " is there a better way to write it elegantly" Yeah, write it without all the bugs.

Comment: It might be lover's blindness but I find `if (test.next && test.next->value > 100)` to be perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Some new languages have an operator that deference only if its left-hand side isn't NULL, return NULL if it is. For example, in C#,

```
test.next?.value
```

is equivalent to

```
test.next == null ? null : test.next.value
```

except `test.next` is only evaluated once.

C doesn't have such an operator. It wouldn't help in this scenario anyway, because you can't perform a numerical comparison of `null` and `100`.

Answer (score 1):

No. C does not have the language feature you seek.

C# does have a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), but C does not.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make it prettier by using line breaks and indenting, e.g.

```
if (test.next &&
    test.next->value > 100)
{
    printf("%s\n", "Big");
}
```

But in general, you'll get used to the language, it won't look so ugly once you get used to it.

Comment: i agree your code is prettier , but maybe it's harder to read :)

Comment: Not to me or my coworkers. You might just have to get used to the language, then find what style works for you. This one is easiest to read for me, but styles might be something that grows on you.